# Why is this css working on demo but not in my project?

Tags: css

The following css is working in web demo and supposed to give an animaton when you hover my logout button but I have many errors with the ::after while putting it in my project. Can anybody help me please?

```
.logout-btn {
font-family: Hack, monospace;
background: #d3d3d3;
color: #2c2c2c;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 2em;
padding: 1.5rem;
border: 0;
transition: all 0.5s;
border-radius: 10px;
width: auto;
position: relative;
min-width: 250px;

&::after {
    content: "\f2f5";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%;
    top: 54%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

&:hover {
    background: #2b2bff;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px #0000ff61;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
    color: #ffffff;

    &::after {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        color: #ffffff;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you linked it all properly and checked your console?

Comment: check your console for any errors or issues

Comment: This is sass, not css; are you sure that online your sass files are compiled to a css file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a preprocessor code (like SASS or PostCSS). If you use vanilla CSS in your project this should give you syntax errors.